# Visual Studio Code JSDoc hide @ tags in tooltip

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I cannot figure out how to hide the '@' tags in the description. Let me show what I am talking about:

What is happening:

[image]

What I would like to hide (marked in red):

[image]

I thought @param should only describe type of the argument in the top of the tooltip, and not show up in the description itself.
How do I hide it? I couldn't find solution in here. Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Why would you want to hide it ? It's useful information, that's why it's part of the JSDoc

Comment: Ask this on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), this isn't really a code related question fit for the Stack Overflow community. Though I strongly doubt you can remove this. What that's showing you is the original JSDoc comment for clarity reasons.

Comment: @sgarcia.dev I'd argue that this is related to JSDoc, so programming, and thus has its place on SO. "Stack Overflow is for programmers, Super User is for computer hardware & software enthusiasts and power users." (https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: Oh so it's by design. I was hoping it's not, because I've seen some buildin methods that had descriptions and argument types without those @ tags, for example [console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW4bw.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Seblor I'd agree with you if his question was about how to achieve X result using JSDoc. However, the main focus of his question is how to modify VSCode (aka: Software) so it's autocomplete doesn't display the original JSDoc Source code behind a function. Not how to document something in JSDoc. I agree it's kind of murky, but it appears to be clearly a Software GUI related question more than it is a code one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is I cannot hide @ tags. I'll learn to live with that. Thank you guys for help.

Comment: I just wanted to kindly inform you that an answer should answer the original question, not a personal conclusion.

Comment: @AdamGenshaft I just wanted to kindly inform you that the answer I provided answers the original question, which was "How do I hide it?"